# How to select a database entry based on multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I am very new to relational databases. I have a postgresql table with prices that are based on multiple foreign keys:

```
price    age_id    type_id    code_id

8.9      5         3          8
...      ...    ...     ...
```

So age_id, type_id and code_id are the foreign keys and point to the value of the entries. They are stored in separate tables:

```
age_id    age
...       ...
5         49
...       ...
```

and

```
type_id   type
...       ...
3         FAM
...       ...
```

and

```
code_id   code
...       ...
8         769894
...       ...
```

How do I get an entry for the price (e.g. 8.9) based on the values of age, type and code? I would have to get the ids of each of these tables and then select the entry from the main table, right?
I don't know how to approach this in a efficient manner. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read about `JOIN`.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` . . . three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3 inner joins:

```sql
SELECT price
FROM price_table
INNER JOIN age_table
ON age_table.id = price.age_id
INNER JOIN type_table
ON type_table.id = price.type_id
INNER JOIN code_table
ON code_table.id = price.code_id
WHERE age = 49
  AND type = 'FAM'
  AND code = 769894
```

I would suggest to check the following:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That's so useful. Thank you. If the table would contain multiple values of price that satisfy the age, type and code, it does not change anything regarding the SELECT?